# What is the difference between 希望　要望　志望　野望?

Tags: word-choice, words

I'm trying to understand the difference between the those words. After looking up in a dictionary, there entries list (roughly) "to wish" .
But I think, that's because they are all written with the kanji 望 (desire?) right?

Can someone explain me those words more in detail?

Feel free to use example sentences.

Comment: Might also want to add [願望]{がん・ぼう}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **希望**: [noun, suru-verb] wish, (abstract and beautiful) hope
- **願望**: [noun] (concrete) wish, will, desire
- **要望**: [noun, suru-verb] request (as in feature request, support request, ...)
- **志望**: [noun] (only used in the context of deciding one's life course) intention, wish, choice; [suffix forming a no-adjective] aspiring; would-be; wannabe
- **野望**: [noun] ambition