# What are the differences between 望み, 志望, 希望 and 願い?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Could anyone explain to me what the differences are between these words, both in meaning and usage?

Comment: Related, but only covers two of the words: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55327/what-is-the-difference-between-%e5%b8%8c%e6%9c%9b-%e8%a6%81%e6%9c%9b-%e5%bf%97%e6%9c%9b-%e9%87%8e%e6%9c%9b

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **望み**

  - *hope* (expectation for future / expectation of surviving, sustaining)

    > 望みを捨てるな *don't give up hope*
  - *desire, wish* (expectation of obtaining / achieving)

    > 望み薄 *fat chance*
- **志望**

  - *aim of becoming* (of profession, school etc.)

    > 志望動機 *reason for applying* (for the job etc.)
- **希望**

  - *hope*; sounds slightly more bookish, but also more modern than 望み
  - *wish, preference* (request out of one's taste)

    > 希望が通る *request is met*
- **願い**

  - *wish, hope* (which is not necessarily fulfilled by one's own effort)

    > 願いがかなう *wish comes true*
  - [suffixing] *letter of (request for)*...

    > 退職願 *resignation letter*

The word forms you provided are nouns, but of course they can be used as verbs with respective meanings.